# Python: Extract unique index values and use them in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, indexing

I would like to apply the loop below where for each index value the unique values of a column called SERIAL_NUMBER will be returned. Essentially I want to confirm that for each index there is a unique serial number.

```
index_values = df.index.levels

for i in index_values:
    x = df.loc[[i]]
    x["SERIAL_NUMBER"].unique()
```

The problem, however, is that my dataset has a multi-index and as you can see below it is stored in a frozen list. I am just interested in the index values that contain a long number. The word "vehicle" also as an index can be removed as it is repeated all over the dataset.

How can I extract these values into a list so I can use them in the loop?

```
index_values
>>
FrozenList([['0557bf98-c3e0-4955-a23f-2394635ab531', '074705a3-a96a-418c-9bfe-14c37f5c4e6f', '0f47e260-0fa2-40ba-a417-7c00ea74248c', '17342ca2-6246-4150-8080-96d6125cf2b5', '26c6c0d1-0134-4b3a-a149-61dd93afab3b', '7600be43-5d0a-49b3-a1ee-fd107db5822f', 'a07f2b0c-447c-4143-a361-d7ddbffdcc77', 'b929801c-2f32-4a95-bfc4-48a05b48ee01', 'cc912023-0113-42cd-8fe7-4df4005127c2', 'e424bd02-e188-462e-a1a6-2f4ed8fe0a2d'], ['vehicle']])
```

Comment: could you add the data to create the FrozenList? If it always looks like this you can probably just go for `index_values_as_list = [item for item in index_values[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

without an example its hard to judge, but I think you need

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).unique() # add .tolist() if you want a list
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5]*5, 'B' : [6]*5})
df = df.set_index('A',append=True)

df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')


df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()
Int64Index([5], dtype='int64', name='A')
```

---

to drop duplicates from an index level use the `.duplicated()` method.

```
df[~df.index.get_level_values(1).duplicated(keep='first')]


   B
  A
0 5  6
```